# Is it possible to use Collector and Survey123 to generate new fields and append to existing records simultaneously?

Tags: arcgis-collector, arcgis-survey123

What I am trying to do is make a webmap for Collector that field staff will use to collect a single piece of information at the same locations monthly.  In this case they are gathering groundwater elevation.  I was able to set up the webmap for Collector and link a survey from Survey123.  However, this creates a whole new record each time.  I was hoping to make the survey add {month_year} and they could add their measurement.

I think I am overreaching the capabilities of Survey123/Collector.  My backup is just using Collector and adding a new field prior to the fieldwork each month, unless someone has a better suggestion.

Comment: Changing the table layout isn't really something that *should* be done with each insert, so it's not a surprise that it isn't easily accomplished.  You can denormalize your data as part of a processing script, but it still shouldn't alter the table (just organize the row contents).